# setting accept-language in header

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I am using an API and in the `GET` request it wants this:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: sv
From: my@domain.com
```

My code looks like this:

```
var full_url = "http://api.arbetsformedlingen.se/af/v0/platsannonser/matchning?nyckelord=it";
$.ajax({
    typ: 'GET',
    url: full_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json', 
        from: 'my@domain.com', 
        accept-language: 'sv'
    }
});
```

When I add the `accept-language: sv` I get this:

> Unexpected token -

What am I doing wrong here? The API is saying that it needs to have those 3 parameters for it to work.

Comment: yes, in the documentation it gives me an example "Accept-Language: sv"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is because you need to wrap the header names in quotes otherwise the `-` is interpreted by JS as a subtraction operator - hence why it is unexpected within the object. Try this:

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json', 
    'From': 'my@domain.com', 
    'Accept-Language': 'sv'
}
```